# How to merge two arrays into one? Retain array elements and length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays in my project right now, I am looking to merge or join them so I can have the result output to a table.

```
var array1 = ["a","b"];
var array2 = ["x", "y"];
```

I know there are methods like `concat` and `push`, but I can't seem to find a method for exactly what I'm trying to do, because `concat` just adds to the array.

My expected output is

```
var combinedarray = ["x and a","y and b"];
```

Comment: please add any additional information by [edit]ing your post

Comment: could you have a possible third array?

Comment: Also, what should happen if the arrays don't contain an equal amount of items? (i.e., `array1.length !== array2.length`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` with the extra index argument of the callback function, so you can get the corresponding value from the second array:

```js
var array1 = ["a","b"];
var array2 = ["x", "y"];
var result = array1.map((a,i) => `${a} and ${array2[i]}`);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: For adding var array3 in the mix, would "var result = array1.map((a,i) => `${a} and ${array2[i]} and ${array3[i]}`);" work?

Comment: Sure, did you try it?

Comment: nvm answered my own question there, it does work! this looks very clean

Comment: thank you very much!! i ended up implementing yours per @AndrewL67 recommendation

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple `for loop` like this:

```js
var array1 = ["a","b"];
var array2 = ["x", "y"];
var combinedarray = [];

for (i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  combinedarray.push(array1[i] + " and " + array2[i]);  
}

console.log(combinedarray);
```

---

Using the **map()** method as shown by @trincot would be a more concise and cleaner way of doing it though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using `reduce()` over the `array2`:

```js
var array1 = ["a","b"];
var array2 = ["x", "y", "z"];

let res = array2.reduce(
    (acc, e, i) => acc.push(e + " and " + (array1[i] || "?")) && acc,
    []
);

console.log(res);
```

Also, this can be shortened a little using the spread operator:

```js
var array1 = ["a","b"];
var array2 = ["x", "y", "z"];

let res = array2.reduce((acc, e, i) => [...acc, e + " and " + (array1[i] || "?")], []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the transposed array and join the elements later for getting a readable string.

```js
var array1 = ["a","b"],
    array2 = ["x", "y"],
    result = [array1, array2]
        .reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]), [])
        .map(a => a.concat(a.splice(-2, 2).join(' and ')).join(', '))

console.log(result);
```

An example with three arrays.

```js
var array1 = ["a","b"],
    array2 = ["x", "y"],
    array3 = ["1", "2"],
    result = [array1, array2, array3]
        .reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]), [])
        .map(a => a.concat(a.splice(-2, 2).join(' and ')).join(', '))

console.log(result);
```